# Computer Vision with Mathematica

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, wolfram-mathematica

Does anybody here do computer vision work on Mathematica? I would like to know what external libraries are available for doing that. The built in image processing functions are not enough. I am looking for things like SURF, stereo, camera calibration,  multi-view geometry etc.

How difficult would it be to wrap OpenCV for use in Mathematica?

Comment: dunno bout mathematica, but matlab might be better suited for your needs.

Comment: I second the use of Matlab for computer/machine vision.

Comment: I really enjoy programming in Mathematica, and hence was looking for solutions in it.

Answer (score 7):

Apart from the extensive set of image processing tools that are now (version 8) natively present in Mathematica, and which include a number of CV algorithms like [finding morphologic objects](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/MathematicalMorphology.html), [image segmentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/SegmentationAnalysis.html) and [feature detection](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/FeatureDetection.html) (see figure below), there's the new [LibraryLink](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/LibraryLink.html) functionality, which makes working with DLLs very easy. You wouldn't have to change OpenCV much to be able to call it from Mathematica. Just some wrappers for the functions to be called and you're basically done.

[image]

Comment: I'd like to represent a mapping of the whole lunar surface on a sphere (also the dark side of the Moon) with a satisfactory fidelity. Do you know any references how to do it in Mathematica ?

Comment: @ArtesDocendo There are three demos in the "Applications" section of the Texture doc page that do this.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think such a thing exists, but I'm getting started.

It has the advantage that you can perform some analytic methods... for example rather than hacking in openCV or even Matlab endlessly, you can compute analytically a quantity, and see that the method leading to this matrix is numerically unstable as a function of input variables. Thus you do not need to hack, as it would be pointless.

As for wrapping opencv, that doesn't seem to make sense. The correct procedure would be to fix bad implementations in opencv based on your analysis in Mathematica and on paper.

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with Peter, I don't believe that forcing Mathematica to use OpenCV is a great thing.

All of the computer vision people that I've talked to, read about, and seen examples are using Matlab and the Imaging toolkit. Its either that, or go with a OpenCV compatible language + OpenCV.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica has a [rich set of tools for image processing](http://www.wolfram.com/solutions/industry/image-processing/), but I'm uncertain about the computer vision capabilities.